# Propogate drop down lists along column based on pre-determined cell references?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of cell references to data in another sheet, without the equal sign (!SheetName$C$2:$C$5). Lets call this column A. These references are more or less in an arbitrary order compared to the host sheet and can repeat as well down this column. If I'd like to automatically fill a separate column with drop down lists, the values of which would correlate with the data attached to these cell references, what would be the best way? Ideally I'd try to select an entire empty column, go to Data->Data Validation->Allow List-> and then for source put something like (=(A1)) , which being a relative reference would allow it to propagate down the column. But obviously me trying to add the equal sign in at that stage of the process to make the cell reference register is incorrect. Changing the list of references itself to a drop down also seems to involve manually choosing the original data in the other sheet anyway, which defeats the purpose of me trying to do this automatically. Thank you for any help.